# Proving limits involving $n$th roots

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I prove that:

1. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{a}-1)=\ln a$, $\forall a>0$
2. $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)=\infty$

I was trying using the following $$\dfrac{x}{x+1}<\dfrac{2x}{x+2}<\ln(x+1)<x$$ but I can't prove that.

Using sequences not L'H's rule.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's Rule works for the first limit.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n (\sqrt[n]{a}-1)= \frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{\frac 1n}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-\frac{\ln a}{n^2}\sqrt[n]{a}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}=\ln a \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a}= \ln a.$$

It also will work for the second, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: use the Taylor series of the exponential function to approximate $a^{1/n}=e^{\ln(a)/n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me bring proof from the "no L'Hôpital, no Taylor".

I start with inequality $\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n <e <  \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1} \right)^n$ for $n>1$ and finding from it $1<n \left(e^{\frac{1}{n}} -1\right)<1+\frac{1}{n-1}$, so we obtain

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n \left(e^{\frac{1}{n}} -1\right)=1$$

Now let's take $a>1$ and denote $y_n=n \left(a^{\frac{1}{n}} -1\right)=n \left(e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}} -1\right)=z_n \left(e^{\frac{1}{z_n}} -1\right) \ln a$, where $z_n=\frac{n}{\ln a} \to +\infty,n \to \infty$. Now we consider $\alpha_n=\left\lfloor z_n \right\rfloor$, so $\alpha_n \leqslant z_n < \alpha_n +1$ and $\frac{1}{\alpha_n +1}< \frac{1}{z_n} \leqslant \frac{1}{\alpha_n }$. We can obtain

$$\alpha_n\ln a  \left(e^{\frac{1}{\alpha_n+1}} -1\right)< y_n < (\alpha_n+1)\ln a  \left(e^{\frac{1}{\alpha_n}} -1\right)$$
as $\alpha_n \left(e^{\frac{1}{\alpha_n}} -1\right)$ is subsequence of $n \left(e^{\frac{1}{n}} -1\right)$, then it have same limit and simple transformations gives

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}y_n=\ln a$$

For case $0<a<1$ we can consider $\frac{1}{a}$.